# openssl passwd crypt algorithm and salting function

Tags: password, encryption

I have been playing around with the command:

```
$openssl passwd -crypt -salt
```

And I really need to see the actual code for which the crypt algorithm and the function for salting the user's input password prior to it's encryption.

Where or how do I view documentation relating to these codes and the code themselves?

Also I was wondering if there is a package that I can modify these definitions so I can discover how all the different flavours of spam are made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the source via `apt-get source openssl`. Documentation? That's what search engines are for.

Comment: Um I got the points because I was already a member of another community, but there is normally a little message reminding you that I am a new contributor and you need to be nice to me